# Creating new line using knockout text

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js, single-page-application, javascript-databinding

I am creating SPA. I am using knockout and observable array to iterate json array. Sometimes i've got br tag inside text, and using data-bind="text: myVar" I would like to brek line. Problem is, br tags wont work, because i can see <br /> except new line. My question is: how can I force knockout data-bind to create new line using this br tags from json data?. I was trying to use "white-space: pre-wrap", but didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to bind using `html:` instead of `text:` and it will process the `<br />`.

**Run the below snippet:**

```js
var viewModel = {
  myVal: ko.observable('First Line <br />Second Line <br />Third Line')
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<h2>Text Binding:</h2>
<span data-bind="text: myVal"></span>
<h2>HTML Binding:</h2>
<span data-bind="html: myVal"></span>
```